# A sincere apology to our community from ex user310476

Tags: discussion

I, ex *user310476*, would like to apologise for both the verbal and physical harm I did to the community.

## Why I am apologising

I decided I can’t continue on this site in clean conscience the same way I used to before until I apologise to the community. I deleted myself from this site at the end of March 2019 and a few months ago added this site to the *Your communities* list with a purpose of visiting every once in a while.

Before I continue in editing, answering and engaging with users I need to come clean and deliver an apology both to the community and some specific people.

## What I did

I did several things which I regret very much:

- provided low quality contributions
- had an agressive temper in chat
- didn’t listen to advice from experienced users
- didn’t listen to moderators
- vandalised other users posts

## Who am I apologising to?

I am apologising to the community in general for damaging it with my harmful activity.

I would like to specifically apologise to:

- the moderators for my disruption but am thankful for their patience with me
- nohillside and bmike for the way I dealt with them in particular
- Allan for using bad tone when you were giving constructive criticism
- The people’s posts whom I vandalised

**Can we move forward please?**

Comment: All fine from my side. Thanks for reaching out, I'm looking forward to your future contributions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In short, yes we can (move forward).

It takes maturity and humility to own up to your mistakes and apologise, and I am sure that most users who were impacted by your earlier behaviour will be willing and able to move forward.

Since you've specifically mentioned bmike, nohillside and Allan in your apology, I won't answer for them here as they may want to respond directly.

However, I know our elected moderators and high rep users are always willing to work with others to help them understand how the site works and what's expected (both in terms of the site's features and how one conducts themselves in relation to other users).

So long as you're willing to listen to advice if/when the time comes, I'm sure you'll find you too will be a highly valued user of this community.

And, on that note, I look forward to your continued involvement.